# How to apply specific stylesheet depends on screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gwt

I want script in html which will identify the screen resolution, and then depends on that I want to link respective stylesheet for the application.

e.g. if the resolution is in between  600x400 then I want to apply mobile.css else normal web.css.

Is it possible? If yes then How to achieve this?

I am not using jquery...I am having GWT application, and I want to add this check to the html file.

Comment: I removed your [tag:java] tag as this appears to have nothing to do with the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now add this line in your

**Head tag**

**as like this**

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> // add this line in your head
</head>
```

**[More info](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps)**

Used to CSS Media Queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

// here your stylesheet 
    }
```

**[More info Click here](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)**

Comment: Might want to remove those comments (or make them html comments), if copied and pasted they will break the page.

Comment: @Ambrosia now check to this fiddle and resize the screen and see the effect http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/2Yw5Q/

Comment: It will work for 600px screens but what about other....?? if my device has greater that 600...It has to be dynamically decided...

Comment: You can use lots of rules, follow the links in this answer and it will all be easy!

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [css media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries) for this.

This means you can have all your rules in one stylesheet, and share common rules.
It also means you only have one file to update when you change things.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a good guide on how to do this

http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible like this:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
if ($(window).width() <= 600 && $(window).height() <= 400) {
    style.src = 'mobile.css';
} else {
    style.src = 'normalweb.css';
}
document.body.appendChild(style);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to write some javascript functions for CSS intercepted by media queries, you can use this cool library: https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js