# can't target IE10 and IE 11 css in specific screen ratio

Tags: html, css

I am using

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  }
```

**for targeting IE10 and IE11** with CSS but the problem is that I want to target specific screen dimensions, something like

```
 @media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) { .span2{ width: 20px;}}.
```

so any help?

Comment: You want to append specific styles to screen that have a specific width?

Comment: aha that's what i want

Comment: With the launch of IE10, they did away with conditional targeting

information here at the bottom of the page http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

IE10 and IE11 will display like other browsers with some extra code. I ran into this exact issue yesterday.

What is the reason for a separately targeted IE10 & 11 stylesheet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply specific stylesheet depends on screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166537/how-to-apply-specific-stylesheet-depends-on-screen-resolution)

Comment: no i don't want to use different stylesheets i have my styles and it works for all browsers except some issues in some screen resolution in IE and i can't target them

Answer (score 2):

finally i found the answer here:  http://browserhacks.com/

```
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) { _:-ms-input-placeholder, :root .span2{  width: 20px;}}
```